# What's the motivation behind kfreebsd

Tags: debian, freebsd

I use both FreeBSD and Debian-based Linuxes on a daily basis. (I am mostly a user/developer/sysadmin not an OS-developer).

I want to know what is the motivation behind kFreeBSD? Why people may want to use FreeBSD kernel but avoid the user land?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the following reasons, are the benefits you get from the FreeBSD kernel:

- Standardized kernel interfaces:

  - Single /dev implementation via devfs, instead of the 3 discordant
    ways of handling /dev that Linux provides.
  - OSS as the default sound system (i.e. the standard interface
    supported by almost every Unix-like system around).
  - OpenBSD Packet Filter (pf).
- Security features, like [jails](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=jail).
- Support for NDIS drivers in the mainline kernel. On Linux,
  NdisWrapper is unlikely to make it into the mainline kernel.
- Support for ZFS in the mainline kernel. Due to license and patent
  issues, ZFS is unlikely to appear on Linux.
- kFreeBSD is less vulnerable to legal issues. Licenses are managed in
  a centralized manner compared to Linux kernel's bazaar-like
  development model.
- kFreeBSD developers often have more interest in merging new features
  rather than spawning forks all along (the port to Xbox is a very good
  example).
- kFreeBSD may have better performance and/or stability especially in
  disk/filesystem areas with ZFS.
- The FreeBSD kernel might support some hardware which Linux does not
  support and/or the FreeBSD kernel support might be better (fewer bugs).

**Why would you prefer Debian GNU/kFreeBSD to FreeBSD?**

- if you like the Debian package system (or its package set) more than
  FreeBSD ports (just a matter of preference).
- If you like GNU userland more than BSDish one (again, just a matter
  of preference).
- If you don't have anything against GPL or other copylefted free
  software licenses, you'll appreciate that useful kernel modules like
  ext2fs driver, the upcoming reiserfs and xfs, or the upcoming
  ethernet driver for Xbox are (or will be) compiled in on the default
  kernel.
- If you're concerned about running a 100% free system, our commitment
  to the Debian Free Software Guidelines (DFSG) guarantees that Debian
  GNU/kFreeBSD doesn't contain any non-free software. In fact, we have
  removed some non-free binary-only drivers that are contained in the
  upstream FreeBSD tree.

From the official [wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/Debian_GNU/kFreeBSD_why), there you can find more points on why to prefer the Debian GNU/Linux and not be totally FreeBSD.

Comment: Thanks, still, as I understand, all these are arguments in favor of FreeBSD, not kFreeBSD, I mean if you want these, why you not use FreeBSD as a whole, or may be I am missing something here?

Comment: see my last line. I will edit my post to include that soon.

Comment: Yep, so it is mostly a matter of tast, plus some legal/licence issues?

Comment: @Ali; most of the distros out there, are matter of taste or legality isn't?

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons to avoid FreeBSD userland:

- Lack of many packages which debian can provide
- Easily available flash support without any emulation
- Awareness about Linux applications is, in general, more than awareness about bsd applications.

In no way I am criticizing either of the operating systems. Both serve their purpose well. kfreeBSD is an attempt to combine best of both worlds.